# Rule that runs macro when an email is opened

Tags: vba, outlook

I have created a macro, that does certain things, to an opened mail. I would like to create a rule, that does it automatically, when I open the mail.

I don't want this rule to run all time, just when I open a mail, I don't want to force this rule on each mail I receive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following @ZZA comments,

try this code:

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        Set myItem = Item
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub myItem_Open(Cancel As Boolean)

   'Your code
End Sub
```

Paste code in ThisOutlookSession
[image]

**EDIT**

To avoid `'Your code` triggering the event we need an event disabler:

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Public EventsDisable as Boolean

Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If EventsDisable = True Then Exit Sub
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        Set myItem = Item
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub myItem_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
    EventsDisable=True
   'Your code
    EventsDisable=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried to test it by just adding: msgbox "test" to it, but it doesn't work, and I can't run this macro, cause it takes you to the screen, where you have to select which macro to run.

Comment: Did you paste your code in `ThisOutlookSession` object?

Comment: Yeah, I did, but I had to restart outlook, and now it works, but it doesn't do what I need it to be done. When I select a mail, the messagebox pops up, and not when I open the mail.

Comment: Okay, now I have added: Set msg = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1), where msg is an outlook.mailitem  

 I think a way to do it, is to determine if the msg is opened, displayed, but find no way.

Comment: You got it! I was struggling with Set msg = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1). The key is the Open event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865989.aspx

Comment: Did you test it? It still doesn't work for me. tested with the usual msgbox, but nothing happens.    And after I've read the msdn article, I am confused a bit, does it only work, if the mail is unread?

Comment: It is working for me at the moment. The only drawback is that new emails are triggered as well.

Comment: Now i see, you have edited again your answer. It works fine with msgbox, but If i kust paste a very short code, it doesn't work. Maybe I used bad declarations?         .  . Dim reply As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Original As Outlook.MailItem
Set Original = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)


Set reply = myItem.reply

reply.Display
reply.OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested = True

Comment: See my last edit. When you create a reply you are triggering the event Application_ItemLoad. And your code is a pretty handy script! Can I keep it? :)

Comment: Also be careful with `Set Original= Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)`, it should read `Set Original=myItem`

Comment: Thank you for helping me :)
It works fine now, but I have to go, and cant test furthermore. If I have anymore problems I may comment again tomorrow. Use it :)

Comment: Hi, somehow the myItem_Open() seems to be not triggered when I use this code. Has something changed in Outlook 2016?

Comment: Works great, thank you @hstay. I used the code in the edit and it works perfect