# How to to populate the From, To, Cc of an email from a template?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm using VBA in Outlook to call an email template. I want the VBA to populate the From, To, Cc fields.

VBA opens the template and creates a new email message but the From, To and Cc fields are empty.

```vb
Sub Step_1()
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Myfolder\Templates\Action Required documents needed.oft")
    
    With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "homebase@gmail.com"
        .To = "Jane.Doe@customer.com"
        .CC = "homebase@gmail.com"
        msg.Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `With msg` not `With OutMail`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, there are two approaches:

1. using **CreateItem** method in order to create default items
2. using **CreateItemFromTemplate** method so you can create items based on templates

Let's start with the first approach. The syntax is as follow: `expression.CreateItem(ItemType)`, where the `expression` returns `Application` object and `ItemType` is a required argument (you can choose from: `olContactItem`, `olDistributionItem`, `olMailItem` etc.). So you can create a new email message like this:

```
Sub email_option1()
Dim msg As MailItem
Set msg = Application.CreateItem(ItemType:=olMailItem)
With msg
  .To = 'recipient
  .CC = 'CCs
  .Subject = 'subject
  .Body = 'body of the email
  .Attachments.Add ("C:\Attachments\Test File.docx") 'if any attachments needed
  .Importance = olImportanceHigh 'if it is important
  .Display 'or .Send
End With
Set msg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Or you can choose the second approach, probably wanted by you as you mentioned having a template ready to use. The syntax would be: `expression.CreateItemFromTemplate(TemplatePath, InFolder)`, where again expression returns an `Application` object, `TemplatePath` is required string argument that tells us where the template we want to use is located. `InFolder` is optional argument that I never use (not entirely sure what it does). So your code could be like:

```
Sub email_option2()
Dim msg As MailItem
Set msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Myfolder\Templates\Action Required documents needed.oft")
With msg
  .To = "Jane.Doe@customer.com"
  .CC = "homebase@gmail.com"
  .Subject = 'subject
  .Display 'or .Send
End With
Set msg = Nothing
End Sub
```

As for the `.SentOnBehalfOfName = "homebase@gmail.com"` line. I am not sure it does what you want it to do. Look here: [SentOnBehalfOfName Microsoft Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName), [Issue with SentOnBehalfOfName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331320/set-sentonbehalfofname-on-every-email-sent) or [More on SentOfBehalfOfName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180066/issue-with-sentonbehalfofname). If this is what you want to achieve, then you can simply put this line back to the code.