# Running a script in shared mailbox only when opening a mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I have tried to find answer to my question from all over the web.
Since I don't have so much experience from outlook-vba I decided to ask here.

What I'm trying to do is to run a script when user opens a mail. Also I need to run this script only in shared mailboxes not in users own box.

I've used the code found in users [@ZZA question # 21727768](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727768/rule-that-runs-macro-when-an-email-is-opened) but it has that little annoyance with creating a mail and replying to one also (it runs the script in these cases also). It is helpful but I haven't found a way to apply that code only to cases where user is opening a mail from shared mailbox.

Any help here?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything else besides copy&pasting the code from that question?

Comment: You should take a look at this for working with a shared mailbox http://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/use-macro-assign-messages-shared-mailbox/

Comment: Can you post the script you are trying to run?

Comment: @Tom yes I have tried some IF statements with GetNameSpace method but I think that's not a way to go.

Comment: @Om3r my script is at the moment basically the same as in the mentioned question but in the 'your code' part I just call other sub with the desired function. I get my script work in every mailbox but I want it to work only in shared ones.

Comment: This is what you are looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/us-en/library/office/ff868990.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found an even easier way to do this (this is mostly code from the question linked to, in the OP)

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Public EventsDisable As Boolean



Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If EventsDisable = True Then Exit Sub
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        Set myItem = Item
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub myItem_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
    EventsDisable = True
    'this is the new part
    If myItem.Parent = "NAMEOFYOURSHAREDINBOX" Then
        'your code here
    End If
    EventsDisable = False
End Sub
```

Mostly credits to [hstay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3218398/hstay)

HTH

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. And thanks to @hstay also.