# Change excel macro settings (temporarily) from outlook,when opening an email on outlook specific folder

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, automation, outlook

[image]

On outlook application I created a new folder with name “Template”.
Inside that folder, I manually put some emails, with inside it my excel macro workbooks. 
Macro settings on Excel are `Disable all macros with notification`,
 as a result when I open any macro workbook, I got a security warning that macros have been disabled,
 and I need to click `Enable Content` each time.

[image]

I could not find any way to add these files to a trusted location or even make as trusted document. 
So, as a work around, I need to change **excel macro settings** (temporarily) from outlook when opening any email on that folder “Template” to `Enable all macros` and after close this email or sent it, then revert macro settings again to “Disable all macros with notification”. 
**Note 1,** Sure, I mean change these macro settings @ my machine only and not at the recipient PC. 
**Note 2,** I already using some macros globally inside outlook (auto zoom), and signed these macros by creating a Digital Signature using `SelfCert.exe`، therefore I do not get any security warning when using that macros. 
**Note 3,** I found this question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727768/rule-that-runs-macro-when-an-email-is-opened), But I could not adapt the provided answer to my needs ,and I use office 2016 32Bit on windows 10 64Bit.
In advance grateful for useful comments and answer.

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Public EventsDisable as Boolean

Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If EventsDisable = True Then Exit Sub
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        Set myItem = Item
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub myItem_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
    EventsDisable=True
   'Your code
    EventsDisable=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You'd be better off creating a VSTO COM addin in VB.Net - it will be able to work without prompts.

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to do much unless you enable the macros.

Comment: But, there are already running macro inside `ThisOutlookSession` and this macro is signed by a (personal digital certificate) therefore I do not get any security warning.If there is not any hope with VBA solution ,kindly could you help with creating `VSTO COM addin in VB.Net`

Comment: You can start at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/create-vsto-add-ins-for-office-by-using-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: Please, If I opened an email ,Is it possible to get the name of it's folder (Inbox,sent,...) using vba?

Comment: Sure, `MailItem.Parent` will give you the parent folder. `MailItem.Parent.Name` will give you the name of the parent folder.