# Native VBA method to change Excel Macro Setting

Tags: excel, vba

supposing this option is **already enabled** on Excel Trust Center:

> Enable all macros (not recommended)

I want to change that setting to:

> Disable all except digitally signed macros

I can use the below registry setting and apply by `VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security]
"VBAWarnings"=dword:00000003
```

But, I ask about a native VBA method other than Windows registry editing.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: There isn't one.

Comment: It would be considered a security issue.

Comment: @FaneDuru ,is that means all the settings found in `Trust Center` can not modified by native vba codes?

Comment: Exactly! But they can be modified using Registry keys. I can show a method to add a folder to `Trusted Locations...`

Comment: @FaneDure ,but the problem that this folder is found on outlook, I already post a question (but no answer yet). concerning current question, I will add answer today that (no native method found) to save time for anyone asking the same question.

Comment: Allowing the code change permissions of the code would be nonsense, don't you think ?

Comment: @iDevlop ,below answer will be used from outlook and not from Excel itself, kindly see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71633696/change-excel-macro-settings-temporarily-from-outlook-when-opening-an-email-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, there is no a native VBA method to change Macro Settings.
the available way is by using windows registry key and VBA FileSystemObject (FSO),
**Note**: you have to add reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library`.

```
Sub change_Macro_Settings()

  Dim myWS As Object: Set myWS = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   Dim name As String, value As String, stype As String
    name = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security\VBAWarnings"
     value = "3"
      stype = "REG_DWORD"
       myWS.RegWrite name, value, stype
  
End Sub
```